# Size of long int in c++ showing 4bytes / Can anyone help me why this happens?

Tags: c++

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2X4c.png)Long int is c++ is of 8 byte but my compiler shows me the result of only 4 bytes and then i put same code in online compiler i got 8 byte

[image of mingw64 compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia3DQ.png)

[image of onlie compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHPzo.png)

Comment: Both are valid sizes of a `long`.

Comment: but why this happens online compiler is showing 8 and mingw64 4 bytes ??

Comment: `long` can be any size 32 bit or greater. Use `int64_t` if you want exactly 64 bits

Comment: `but why this happens online compiler is showing 8 and mingw64 4 bytes ??` Because those are different compilers and do things differently. Again, __both__ 32 bit __and__ 64 bit are valid sizes for a `long int` according to the C++ Standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)